# Conditional formatting dates

Tags: excel

in excel i want a field (M2) to highlight with color and add a date that is +30 days,  from another date field (K2). I can do this with number of days but I don't know how to make it add dates. The days I used =Today()+(m2) then use conditional formatting to highlight.  I am lost on how to do the date. thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **M2** cell to following: 
**=DATE(YEAR(K2),MONTH(K2),DAY(K2)+30)**

Take a look at the Documentation:
[Microsoft Office Excel - Add or Substract Dates](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-7cecf4b8-ea80-4355-a878-5e7c2047e3f1)

Comment: Not a specific reason, but the question was to 'make it add dates' and `=K2+30` just adds days.